# dictionary which depends on 2nd dropbox selection with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window=Tk()
window.title("RBEE Model")
window.geometry('500x450')

label7=Label(window,text='Select Pollutant:',fg='black',font=('Arial',14))
label7.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=10)
Pollutant = ["PM2.5","PM10"]


crop_poll = [{'Rice':55,'Wheat':66,'Total Pulses':89,'Total Nine Oilseeds':69},
          {'Total Pulses':89,'Total Nine Oilseeds':69}]


crop_poll_roll = ttk.Combobox(window, width=27, value=(Pollutant))
crop_poll_roll2 = ttk.Combobox(window, width=27, value=(crop_poll))
crop_poll_roll.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10, sticky='w')

def callback2(eventObject2):
    abcd = eventObject2.widget.get()
    crop_p = crop_poll_roll.get()
    index1=Pollutant.index(crop_p)
    crop_poll_model.config(values=list(crop_poll[index1].keys()))
#     crop_poll_model = ttk.Combobox(window, width=27,values=list(crop_poll[index1].keys()))
crop_poll_model = ttk.Combobox(window, width=27)
crop_poll_model.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10, sticky='w')
crop_poll_model.bind('<Button-1>', callback2)

def emissions():
    
    crop_p = crop_poll_roll.get()
    index1=Pollutant.index(crop_p)

#     crop_i=crop_poll_model.get()
#     index2=crop_poll_model.index(crop_i)
    
#     blank.delete(0, tk.END)
    
   
    emiss= float((list(crop_poll[index1].values()))[index1])
#     blank.insert(0, emiss)
    emptylabel.config(text='Emissions:'+ str(emiss))
    
# blank = tk.Entry(window)    
button1=Button(window,command=emissions,text='Calculate Emissions',fg='red',font=('Arial',14))
button1.grid(row=11,column=1)

emptylabel=Label(window,fg='green',font=('Arial',14))
emptylabel.grid(row=12,column=1,pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

This code is working fine I just want to access the value of a dictionary within the list.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsJBQ.jpg)

I have attached the pic of the output here if I select the PM2.5 then I can choose another dropdown list.
so I select rice I want to display the square root of the value 55.
if I select wheat same thing I want to do with value 66 and so on.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your task. There are only two combo boxes here. None of them contain two pollutants. `crop_d` is a string that is not in the `Pollutant` list. What index do you want to find? `crop.keys()` won't work as `crop` is a list of lists, not a dictionary. And each nested list has one element - a dictionary. Which dictionary do you want to display?

Comment: See also [operations supported by dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: I have updated my code and problem. By the way  thank you for replying

Answer (score 0):

You only have two values: `"PM2.5"`(index1=0) and `"PM10"`(index1=1).

When you execute this line of code,

```
emiss= float((list(crop_poll[index1].values()))[index1])
```

it means:

```
emiss= float((list(crop_poll[0].values()))[0])
```

or

```
emiss= float((list(crop_poll[1].values()))[1])
```

These are `'Rice': 55` in the first dictionary and `'Total Nine Oilseeds':69` in the second dictionary.

---

You can get the desired value from the dictionary like this:

```py
import math


def emissions():
    
    crop_p = crop_poll_roll.get()
    index1=Pollutant.index(crop_p)

    # Option 1
    # string, dictionary key
    selected_crop_value = crop_poll_model.get()
    print(f"selected_crop_value: {selected_crop_value}")
    # get value in dict by key
    emiss= float(crop_poll[index1][selected_crop_value])

    # Option 2
    # integer, index in dropdown list
    selected_crop_index = crop_poll_model.current()
    print(f"selected_crop_index: {selected_crop_index}")
    # get the value by the index of its key
    # since version 3.6+, Python dictionaries are ordered
    emiss= float(list(crop_poll[index1].values())[selected_crop_index])
    
    emiss_sqrt = math.sqrt(emiss)
    emptylabel.config(text='Emissions:'+ str(emiss_sqrt))
```

---

See also ttk.Combobox widget methods:

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#combobox)

[Combobox - Tcl/Tk version 8.5](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Combobox.html) (Newer versions of Python use version 8.6, but this link is helpful too).

---

You can also use the combobox event:
`crop_poll_roll.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callback)`

For example, create a callback function for `crop_poll_roll` in which you change the state of `crop_poll_model` depending on whether you select `"PM2.5"` or `"PM10"`.